# Android Oreo 8 unable to fetch packages

Tags: android, android-intent, android-8.0-oreo

I tried fetching browser packages using the below code, I have two web browser, *UC Browser* and *Google Chrome*. But this is not returning me any browsers. This is happening only for `Android Oreo` signed APK for `Google Pixel`.

```
Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
List<ResolveInfo> activities = activity.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(webIntent, 0);
```

Comment: Wel show what you have in String url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
webIntent.setType("text/html");
```

Or try with

```
webIntent.setDataAndType(url,"text/html");
```

Comment: You still did not show your url. Then what does it mean: `Please let me know if you need any additional information regarding the same.` ?

Comment: This is happening for all the urls. I am trying with https://www.google.com

Comment: Please let me know if you need any additional information regarding the same. This means that apart from the information I have provided, if you need any other information let me know.

Comment: setType did not work but setDataAndType worked. setType sets data to null. Thank you very much.